# What could be causing this SQLite CursorWindowAllocationException?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, android-sqlite

My Google Play dev console has reported its first crash to me for my Android app. It looks like SQLite was unable to allocate memory to the cursor, but I've never seen this before and can't reproduce it. Any ideas?

Stackgrace reported by Google:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro/com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro.Activity_Category}: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=530 (# cursors opened by this proc=530)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=530 (# cursors opened by this proc=530)
at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:108)
at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:100)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:301)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
at com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro.DBAdapter.getCourse(DBAdapter.java:401)
at com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro.Activity_Category$CategoryActivityFragment.setListData(Activity_Category.java:196)
at com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro.Activity_Category$CategoryActivityFragment.onCreateView(Activity_Category.java:182)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1189)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5436)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
... 11 more
```

Where it failed in my DBAdapter class.

```
public Course getCourse (int rowId) throws SQLException {
        Cursor c =
                db.query(true, TABLE_COURSES, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_YEAR, KEY_SEASON, KEY_CREDIT}, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        Course course = new Course(c.getInt(0), c.getString(1), c.getInt(2), c.getString(3), c.getDouble(4));
        return course;
    }
```

Where the DBAdapter function is called. At this point in the activity, the db has already been opened, queried, and closed successfully.

```
public void setListData(){
            db.open();
            Grade[] g = db.getGradesInCategory(catId);
            this.getActivity().setTitle(db.getCourse(courseId).getTitle());
            db.close();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is an `OutOfMemoryError`, in effect. Quoting [the comments for that exception class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/CursorWindowAllocationException.java):

> This exception is thrown when a CursorWindow couldn't be allocated, most probably due to memory not being available.

The error message shows that you have 530 open `Cursor` objects, which may be part of your problem. For example, you are leaking a `Cursor` in your `getCourse()` method. Make sure that you close your `Cursor` as soon as you are done with it.

If that does not help, you will need to treat this like an `OutOfMemoryError` and determine where else you are wasting heap space, perhaps by [using tools like MAT](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html).

Comment: Oh wow. It didn't register with me that I had that many cursors open. I had gotten the impression (don't remember how) that it was not always necessary to close cursors. Currently, none of my db calls close the cursor. I suppose I should fix that! Oops.

Comment: Hmm. Sometimes I use `return cursor.getString(0)`. I guess I can't close the cursor after a return, nor return using it after a close. I'll have to return temp variables, right?

Comment: @NSouth: "I'll have to return temp variables, right?" -- if you mean local variables (stuff declared in the method body), then yes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Cursors need to be closed:

```java
Cursor c = db.query(...);
try {
    ...
} finally {
    c.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to mess with multiple local variables to return, you can return the Cursor object and then close it from the calling method.

This is in response to " Hmm. Sometimes I use return cursor.getString(0). I guess I can't close the cursor after a return, nor return using it after a close. I'll have to return temp variables, right? –  NSouth Oct 4 '14 at 20:44: &

@NSouth: "I'll have to return temp variables, right?" -- if you mean local variables (stuff declared in the method body), then yes. –  CommonsWare Oct 4 '14 at 20:46

I know this is more of a comment then a answer, but I do not have the reputation points to comment and thought this might be helpful.